# CMake: set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True) causing configuration error

Tags: c++, cmake

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:12 (target_include_directories):
  Cannot specify include directories for target "myproject" which is
  not built by this project.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/user/project-path/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/user/project-path/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

This error appears to be caused by this line in the `CMakeLists.txt`. Removing this line "fixes" the problem.

Full disclosure: I don't really know what this line does, or if it is required.

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)
```

Here is the full contents of my `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)

project(myproject VERSION 1.0)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE DEBUG)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH /home/user/project-path)

configure_file(version.hpp.in version.hpp)
target_include_directories(myproject PUBLIC "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}")

find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
find_package(SDL2TTF REQUIRED)
include_directories(myproject ${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${SDL2TTF_INCLUDE_DIR})

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)

add_executable(myproject ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(myproject ${SDL2_LIBRARIES} ${SDL2TTF_LIBRARY} fontconfig)
```

Here is some relevant content from the file `CMakeError.log`

```
Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/gmake cmTC_3abe6/fast && /usr/bin/gmake  -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_3abe6.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_3abe6.dir/build
gmake[1]: Entering directory '/home/.../build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_3abe6.dir/src.c.o
/usr/bin/cc   -DCMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_3abe6.dir/src.c.o -c /home/.../build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.c
Linking C executable cmTC_3abe6
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_3abe6.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/cc  -DCMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD CMakeFiles/cmTC_3abe6.dir/src.c.o -o cmTC_3abe6 
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/cmTC_3abe6.dir/src.c.o: in function `main':
src.c:(.text+0x2f): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
/usr/bin/ld: src.c:(.text+0x3b): undefined reference to `pthread_detach'
/usr/bin/ld: src.c:(.text+0x47): undefined reference to `pthread_cancel'
/usr/bin/ld: src.c:(.text+0x58): undefined reference to `pthread_join'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_3abe6.dir/build.make:106: cmTC_3abe6] Error 1
gmake[1]: Leaving directory '/home/.../build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
gmake: *** [Makefile:140: cmTC_3abe6/fast] Error 2


Source file was:
#include <pthread.h>

void* test_func(void* data)
{
  return data;
}

int main(void)
{
  pthread_t thread;
  pthread_create(&thread, NULL, test_func, NULL);
  pthread_detach(thread);
  pthread_cancel(thread);
  pthread_join(thread, NULL);
  pthread_atfork(NULL, NULL, NULL);
  pthread_exit(NULL);

  return 0;
}

Determining if the function pthread_create exists in the pthreads failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /home/.../build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/gmake cmTC_f3bc6/fast && /usr/bin/gmake  -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_f3bc6.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_f3bc6.dir/build
gmake[1]: Entering directory '/home/.../build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_f3bc6.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o
/usr/bin/cc   -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=pthread_create -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_f3bc6.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o -c /usr/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/CheckFunctionExists.c
Linking C executable cmTC_f3bc6
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_f3bc6.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/cc  -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=pthread_create CMakeFiles/cmTC_f3bc6.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o -o cmTC_f3bc6  -lpthreads 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpthreads
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_f3bc6.dir/build.make:106: cmTC_f3bc6] Error 1
gmake[1]: Leaving directory '/home/.../build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
gmake: *** [Makefile:140: cmTC_f3bc6/fast] Error 2
```

I understand that this code is to test if the posix threads are supported on this system, which they should (?) be...

What is causing this to break?

Comment: So the error message is caused by the improper order between `add_executable(myproject ${SOURCE_FILES})` and `target_include_directories(myproject PUBLIC "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}")`. Everything else is irrelevant, including setting of `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED` variable and position of `configure_file`.

Answer (score 1):

I was thrown off by the error. I thought pthreads was missing on Debian 10 for some reason. This was not the case.

This fixed the issue:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)

project(textgraphicslib VERSION 1.0)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE DEBUG)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH /home/ecb/Worlds-Best-Text-Editor-3/Text-Graphics-Lib)

find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
find_package(SDL2TTF REQUIRED)
include_directories(textgraphicslib ${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${SDL2TTF_INCLUDE_DIR})

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp fc_helper.cpp sdlfontmanager.cpp sdlfontmanager_fontmanagerinitsuccess.cpp sdlfonttexturemanager.cpp fc_helper.cpp)

add_executable(textgraphicslib ${SOURCE_FILES})

configure_file(version.hpp.in version.hpp)
target_include_directories(textgraphicslib PUBLIC "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}")

target_link_libraries(textgraphicslib ${SDL2_LIBRARIES} ${SDL2TTF_LIBRARY} fontconfig)
```

Note that the line `configure_file` has been moved to after `add_executable`. I guess there is an order dependency there which I was not aware of. See also my previous question.

Comment: `include_directories(textgraphicslib ${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${SDL2TTF_INCLUDE_DIR})`... this is wrong. It should be `target_include_directories(textgraphicslib PRIVATE ${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${SDL2TTF_INCLUDE_DIR})` and come after `add_executable`. But you should be using the imported targets, anyway, not the package variables.

Comment: You should also not set `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` in your CMakeLists.txt. It is meant to be set externally.

Comment: You should also never call `target_link_libraries` without at least one of `PRIVATE` (correct for here), `INTERFACE`, or `PUBLIC`. Otherwise you can trigger confusing legacy behaviors

Comment: Finally, you should never place an absolute path to your home directory in **any** build system for any language. You can construct an absolute path with the CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR or CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR variables. Not that you should be assigning to CMAKE_MODULE_PATH anyway... you should only append to it.